# Invalid answer while printing child elements from an XML file in JAVA

Tags: java, xml

Im trying to get the number of child elements of a parent element from a XML file using JAVA. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("SearchPromotions.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

NodeList l = doc.getElementsByTagName("TestCase");
Node parentNode = l.item(0);
int count = parentNode.getChildNodes().getLength();

System.out.println(count);
```

And here is the XML file:

```
<TestCase>
    <SelectedDataTableNames name="SearchData"> </SelectedDataTableNames>

    <Open page="hsbc"  ms="5000"  />
    <Click object="hsbc.Personal_Link"  />
    <Click object="hsbc.CreditCard_tab"  />
    <Call businessComponent="Global.Verify_Search">
       <Param name="HotelName_Param" value="@SearchData_link" />
    </Call>
    <CheckElementPresent object="hsbc.Img_Hotel_logo"  Identifire="Hotel_Name_PARAM:@SearchData_ResultHotelName"  fail="true"  customErrorMessage="Searched hotel name is not present in the page."  />
</TestCase>
```

The problem im facing is that it is printing a wrong value. The value printed is 13. But as you can see there are only 6 child elements for the parent element "TestCase". Where did i go wrong. Please help

Comment: Why don't you print out the Nodes to see what it really gets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for the question. It works. The problem i had was ELEMENT_NODE. We have to filter ELEMENT_NODE. Here is the working code. Thanks for all those who helped be over there.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("SearchPromotions.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();
if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
           if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element el = (Element) nl.item(i);
                System.out.println(el);
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        String fileContent = readFile("SearchPromotions.xml");// Read trimmed file
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));// Create stream to pass it to parser()
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in);

        NodeList l = doc.getElementsByTagName("TestCase");
        Node parentNode = l.item(0);
        int count = parentNode.getChildNodes().getLength();

        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static String readFile(String pathname) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(pathname);
        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine().trim()); // Trim the whitespace. This resuls in TEXT_NODE.
            }
            return fileContents.toString();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
```

There are some white space charcters in your XML which will result in extra nodes. Try the above solution hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But when i tried this one it said that the attribute TestCase has to finish with > or />. But thanks for stopping by

Answer (score 1):

The children of a node include whitespace text nodes as well as child element nodes.

Why not just do this with XPath - it's so much less hassle!

With Saxon and XPath 2.0 it would be

```
Processor p = new Processor(false);
XdmNode doc = p.newDocumentBuilder().build(
    new StreamSource(new File("searchPromotions.xml")));
XdmItem result = p.newXPathCompiler().evaluateSingle("/TestCase/count(*)", doc);
System.out.println(result.getStringValue());
```